# passing a list of variables to simple bash command

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am looking to pass a list of variables from a text file into a simple bash command. Essentially I have a list of all linux commands (commands.txt). I want to pass each command from that file (each is on a new line) to the man command and print each to a new .txt file so each variable would be passed to this:

```
man $command > $command.txt
```

so each variable would have its man page printed to its name .txt. Please help! I would like to do this in bash script but anything that will work would be appreciated.

Comment: I would not pipe the output of `man` blindly like this, since depending on your pager your might have surprises. On my system, my pager is `vim`, and your command would hang my terminal. At least, use `man -P cat $command` to use a more trivial pager (here `cat`). It will also make things slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use built-in command `read`:

```
cat commands.txt | while read command; do
  man $command > $command.txt
done
```

Comment: Use input redirection instead of `cat`: `while read command; do ...; done < commands.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You **CANNOT** redirect output of man page into a file like this:

```
man man > man.txt # DON'T DO THIS
```

Problem with above is that the output man.txt file will contain a lot of extra formatting characters as well.

Here is correct way to write your script:

```
while read command; do
   man $command | col -b > $command.txt
done < commands.txt
```

Note use of `col -b` here to remove all formatting characters.

Comment: This is actually not true, you can man a commands man page into a .txt file just as I mentioned and there are no formatting errors or additions.

Comment: May be on your system it may have worked but I tried it on Mac & Linux and it has all kind of extra formatting characters in the output file.